# Moth identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This moth was found lying on the road in [Bengaluru, India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore). Although it was damaged very badly from the under side, the wing pattern was still intact. Is it still possible to identify it?
It is 9cms from head to wing tip

[image: the moth]

Comment: Hi, the identification process is easier if you can tell us a bit more about it. It's better if you can provide an image without a flash (no bright light either). Where was this bug found (country, state, etc.)? How big is it?

Comment: Oh yes I'm sorry I forgot to mention, it was found in Bangalore

Comment: I have inserted a new picture taken under normal lighting conditions. Thank you for pointing out the error @Aravind Suresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hawkmoth, *Sphingidae*. One of the largest and arguably most beautiful of all moths. I am not familiar enough to  India to pinpoint the species, it might be a member of the genus *Agrius* or *Manduca*.

Here's a picture of a resembling, species from the *Manduca* genus.

[image: the moth]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manduca

Comment: I myself had thought of a hawk moth, however, I didn't think the wing pattern was consistent with the OP. Can you explain to me some of the resemblances? Thanks.

Comment: @Charles the forewing is much longer than the body and covers the (hence much smaller) hindwings.  The forewing is also strongly curved towards the tip. I can't think of any other genus with this shape&size, but am open to learn something! The wing pattern is quite worn, at the tip of the left wing you can see through. That makes thw wing pattern less reliable in this case.

Comment: This isn't a hawk moth; the forewing venation is not correct for that family (it is possible to see that two anal veins reach the wing margin in the OP photo; compare with figure 5 on page 5 [here](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1071&context=tnas); the veins aren't labelled there, but the anal vein is the last vein of the wing).

Comment: @Arthur I see the difference. However, I can't find in the text that this anal vein is a distinctive feature of all Hawk moths (though it very well might be). Do you have any better suggestions? AFAIK most Notodontidae and Noctuidae also have an anal vein reaching the outer margin.

Comment: @RHA while some elements of wing venation vary within Lepidoptera families, the number of anal veins reaching the wing margin in the fore wing isn't one of them (see [here](http://www.mothsofborneo.com/part-3/sphingidae/sphingidae.php) for another discussion of hawk moth wing venation -- sorry that there aren't pictures with this one; that same discussion lists other moth families which have the hind wings much smaller than the fore wings).

Comment: @Arthur I can't find anything about veins on that page.

Comment: @RHA sorry about that; I'd forgotten that not everyone is familiar with insect wing vein names.  It's in the fourth paragraph under the "Adults" header: the abbreviations R2 and R3 refer to the second and third branches  of the radius vein (the third major vein of an insect's wing after the costa -- at the leading margin -- and subcosta -- just after that); in the OP photo the forked vein we can see just past the fore wing apex is the last two branches of the radius: R4 and R5; the next five veins are the three branches of the media and two branches of the cubitus, all off the discal cell.